# Locking individual rows in a subform

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form is reading data with a one to many relationship. In the form I have 5 columns. Each field is manipulable originally. But I want the individual rows to lock after data in column 4 and 5 are filled in. Effectively finishing the record. I have been able to figure out how to close the entire form down, but not individual rows/records.

Here is the code I am using.

```
If IsNullorEmpty(GPInterfaceID) Then
Me.ChargeType.Locked = True
Else
Me.ChargeType.Locked = False
End If
If IsNullorEmpty(GPPostingDate) Then
Me.ChargeType.Locked = True
Else
Me.ChargeType.Locked = False
End If
```

This is the version of the code where I tried locking the individual columns individually. I also tried locking all of them at once.

I am not fluent in VB at all. So any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to lock specific rows in a subform when a form loads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849141/how-to-lock-specific-rows-in-a-subform-when-a-form-loads)

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: As stated above, this is not possible. You might be able to create a workaround by removing the record from your form in the afterupdate event?

Comment: I just split the form into two. One editable, one locked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If IsNullorEmpty(GPInterfaceID) Then
        Me.ChargeType.Locked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The event will fire every time you select a row. If in the selected row GPInterfaceID is empty then Access will lock the field ChargeType. In that moment Access will lock that field in every row but that does not matter because in the moment you click on another row Access will fire the Form_Current() event again and will lock or unlock the field(s).